# Django - Only update FileField column without overriding other columns

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

In Django, I have a **model**:

```
class List(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/', null=True, blank=True)
```

Also, I have a page which is to ONLY upload a file to **List.document** for an **existing** List:
[image]

In **views.py**, I have

```
def upload(request, item_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        item = List.objects.get(pk=item_id)
        form = ListForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=item)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'File saved successfully.')
        else:
            messages.error(request, f'File not saved properly: {form.errors.as_data()}')
        return redirect('home')
```

. However, since the form doesn't include **List.item**, while clicking **Upload**, an error occurs **File not saved properly: {'item': [ValidationError(['This field is required.'])]}**.

The easiest way may be add **List.item** as a **hidden element** in the html:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="document" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Upload</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Nevertheless, is there a better way to get over this? Maybe any options to skip overwriting existing columns?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show me your forms.py and ListForm? Maybe the problems are in there.

Answer (score 1):

I've followed your situation, but save() works well. The followings are codes I tested. You may try this.

**models.py**

```py
from django.db import models

class List(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/', null=True, blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```py
from django import forms
from .models import List

class ListForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = List
        fields = ['document']
```

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import List
from .forms import ListForm

# Create your views here.
def upload(request, item_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        item = List.objects.get(pk=item_id)
        form = ListForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=item)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # messages.success(request, 'File saved successfully.')
        else:
            # messages.error(request, f'File not saved properly: {form.errors.as_data()}')
            pass
        return redirect('home')
    return render(request, 'templates/upload.html', {'form': ListForm()})
```

**upload.html**

```html
<!-- both forms are working -->

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>

<hr/>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="document" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Upload</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
form = ListForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=item)
```

, I should employ

```
from django.forms import modelform_factory
ListForm_ = modelform_factory(List, fields=("document",))
```

to only include necessary fields (i.e., `document`).

Thanks.